# Designing Android Drawable Shapes

Tags: android, xml, shapes, shapedrawable

I'm using Android Studio, is there any better way of designing shapes other then in XML, a designer tool with some sort of a preview would be good.

Any other advice on how to best work with shapes ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and I have looked there is no designer tool for android shapes. My advice to you is to write the file in XML and preview it in a layout file.